# logo centered around unknown menu items

Tags: html, css, menu, center

Having unknown number of menu items and a logo I would like to center the logo around items and logo should be in the middle of screen.

What are the best techniques in this case?

```css
nav {

  text-align:center;

}

ul{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}


li{
  display:inline;

}

li+li{
  margin-left:15px;

}
```

```html
<nav>
<div id="logo"></div>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu6</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu7</a></li>
  
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do want menu and Logo should be in same row.

Comment: yes the logo should be in the same row

Answer (score 1):

Assuming You want logo and `li's`be on the same row... there's no easy solution. I think you need a bit of jquery but You need, whatever solution you find, an even number of `li's`.

With this jquery:

```
var middle = Math.ceil($("ul li").length / 2);
$("ul li:nth-child(" + middle + ")").after('<li class="logo"></li>');
```

You just add an extra `li` in the middle of your `ul` which later you can style adding the image with css:

```
.logo {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background-image:url(your image);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        display:inline-block;
}
```

as in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/hsh99qky/)**

Comment: thank you for feedback. is this a good workaround with not pair numbers?

Comment: there won't never be a good workaround with odd numbers. if you want logo in the middle you will ALWAYS have a different amount of `li's` each side of the logo. It's how it is (and I doubt you will want a `li` over the logo

Answer (score 0):

Use logo in ul li or you can two menus left and right is better. Otherwise you have to do more.

```css
nav {

  text-align:center;

}

ul{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}


li{
  display:inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;

}

li+li{
  margin-left:15px;

}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 13px;
  background: #565656;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

#logo a {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top:35px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
      <li class="logo" id="logo"><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu8</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```